# JavaScript inherit from two different objects

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototype

Given classes `Animal`, `Flying_object`, I want to instantiate a `Bird` and `Boomerang` object according to the following rules :

- `Boomerang` must inherit from `Flying_object` only.
- `Bird` must inherit from both `Animal` AND `flying_object`.

**Problem**: I can't seem to find the proper way to instantiate Bird as both an Animal and a Flying_object.

I can't make `Animal` inherit from `Flying_object` because not all animals are flying objects, neither can I make `Flying_object` inherit from `Animal`, because a boomerang is not an animal.

```
/**
 * Only Bird must inherit this class
*/
var Animal = function() {
    this.className = 'Animal';
};
Animal.prototype.sayClassName = function() {
    console.log('I am a '+ this.className);
};

/**
 * Both Boomerang and Bird must inherit this class
*/
var Flying_object = function() {
    this.className = 'Flying_object';
};
Flying_object.prototype.sayName = function() {
    console.log('I am a '+ this.className);
};
Flying_object.prototype.fly = function() {
    console.log(this.className +' can fly');
}
```

Error trying to instantiate Bird as both Animal and Flying_object:

```
var Bird = function() {
    this.className = 'Bird';
}
Bird.prototype = new Animal();        //----> Bird should inherit from Animal
Bird.prototype = new Flying_object(); //----> It should also inherit from Flying_object
Bird.prototype.sayName = function() {
    console.log('I am a '+ this.className);
};

/**
 * instantiating...    
*/
var bird = new Bird();
bird.sayName();
bird.fly();
bird.isAnimal(); //---> Uncaught TypeError: bird.isAnimal is not a function
```

I understand why I get this error: `Bird.prototype = new Animal();` is overloaded by `Bird.prototype = new Flying_object();` so it really only inherits from Flying_object. Problem is I have no idea how to solve this issue.

Is there any way I can make Bird inherit from BOTH `Animal` and `Flying_object` ? If not, what would be the proper approach to make `bird` share all the properties and methods from `Animal` and `Flying_object` ?

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Hal_9100/9hn30pdz/

Comment: That's not how inheritance, in any language, works.

Comment: @Adam: Well, there are some [multi-inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance) languages (C++, for instance). JavaScript just isn't one of them, but mixins and/or composition are usually good enough.

Comment: @Adam: `Bird.prototype = new Animal();` is actually classical inheritance (although JS doesn't handle inheritance like other OOP languages). My attempt to make `Bird` inherit from both `Animal` and `Flying_object` is indeed not the way multi inheritance works, which is the reason I'm asking how to achieve this in JavaScript

Comment: @T.H. Crowder So if I'm understanding the answer you linked as a duplicate correctly, my only option would be to do something like `Bird.prototype = new Animal(); Bird.prototype.fly_methods = new Flying_object();` and then access it this way: `var bird = new Bird(); bird.fly_methods.fly();`. Am I correct ?